# How can I user docker image jenkins/jnlp-slave with Jenkins docker-swarm-plugin (pass agent name)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have a swarm of three nodes (one manager, two workers). In my swarm, I am running a jenkins service with docker-swarm-plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-swarm-plugin) installed. I want to use the plugin to create a build agent container in my swarm for every jenkins job. For the agents I want to user the jenkins/jnlp-slave docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jnlp-slave/). The image expects two arguments for the start:

1. secret (can be set via JENKINS_SECRET environment variable)
2. agent name (can be set via JENKINS_AGENT_NAME environment variable)

The docker-swarm-plugin creates three environment variables:

1. $DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_SECRET (I use this to set the secret)
2. $DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_JAR_URL
3. $DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_JNLP_URL (this contains the agent name)

I pass the secret to the agent via JENKINS_SECRET environment variable (in ENV section of Jenkins plugin configuration):

```
JENKINS_SECRET=$DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_SECRET
```

I tried to pass the agent name by using a regular expression (also in ENV section of Jenkins plugin configuration):

```
JENKINS_AGENT_NAME=`echo $DOCKER_SWARM_PLUGIN_JENKINS_AGENT_JNLP_URL | sed ...`
```

But the command is not executed (I understand that this is for security reasons to avoid code injection).

What do I want to reach:
I want to run jenkins on my docker swarm and I want jenkins to run every job in an own build agent container that is dropped after the job finished. And I want the build agent containers to spread across the swarm (jenkins docker-plugin launches them on the node where the jenkins master is running). I understood that the docker-swarm-plugin should do exactly what I want to do. And I think the jenkins/jnlp-slave image is there to build agent containers as I want to use. But I can't find a solution how to get them work together.

Can anyone give me some advice?
Should I maybe use another image that is working better with the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened issue https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-swarm-plugin/issues/37 on docker-swarm-plugin for this and now with PR https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-swarm-plugin/pull/39 a new environment variable is added with the created agents name. This can be passed to the docker image and everything works fine!